# Should OAuth 2.0 refresh tokens ask for a userId

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm implementing OAuth 2.0 in my API. We're using JWTs for authentication, and refresh tokens for client-only reauthorization. Should I ask the client to also provide the `userId` in the body of `POST /token` so  that they're required to know the user  and the refresh token together (so you can't just try a bunch of random strings and see what works)? What's the standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing a refresh token should not be possible if the spec is implemented correctly; https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.4 says:

> The authorization server MUST ensure that refresh tokens cannot be
> generated, modified, or guessed to produce valid refresh tokens by
> unauthorized parties.

You must make sure that you generate refresh tokens with enough entropy so that the randomness of your refresh token would not become any different by adding the userid to it. Or to put it yet differently: guessing your refresh token would be just as hard as guessing userid+refresh token. Besides that, adding a user id in the POST would make it actually more predictable than adding a random string to the refresh token with the length of the userid.

Comment: Good point. I was considering the scenario where someone, somehow gets their hands on an access token but doesn't know who it belongs two - sort of a form of two-factor authentication, but I can't actually imagine how that would happen anyway if you were using SSL, and if you weren't using SSL they'd also see the userId :P

Comment: yep, if the two are sent together it is actually hard to see one but not the other; same thing will most probably hold for storage